# Return a sorted iterator of dictionaries based on the keys used for obtaining these dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I wonder if it is possible to achieve the following in Python:

I have a nested dictionary `nested_dict`, which maps each three-element tuple `(a, b, c)` to a sub-dictionary `sub_dict`, and I have another list `list_b` containing all the elements corresponding to the second element (i.e. the one denoted by `b`) in the tuple keys above.

Given `nested_dict` and `list_b`, as well as a fixed pair of `a` and `c` (i.e. the first and the third element of a tuple key, respectively), I want to obtain a **sorted iterator** over the sub-dictionaries **based on the elements in `list_b` that forms a part of the tuple keys**, in other words, by using this iterator, I can iterate through the returned sub-dictionaries like this:

`nested_dict[(a, b_1, c)], nested_dict[(a, b_2, c)], nested_dict[(a, b_3, c)], ...`

where, `b_1 < b_2 < b_3 ...` and each `b_i` is in `list_b`

I am thinking along this line:

```
def sorted_dict_itr (nested_dict, list_b, a, c):
    return (nested_dict[(a, b, c)] for b in sorted(list_b))
```

But would this always return an iterator over `nested_dict[(a, b, c)]` by the order of `b`? If so, is there any more efficient way (meaning speedier code) to achieve the same?

Comment: By "better", are you looking for "more efficient", "easier to understand without needing comments", "more idiomatic", or "less/prettier code"? What you have will work, and it doesn't seem bad to me. It might be clearer, but more code, to define a sorted_dict_generator that just yields the values instead of a sorted_dict_itr that returns a generator that yields the values. It might (depending on your larger use case) be more efficient to keep a sorted collection of the b's instead of sorting list_b each time. There's lots of other such comments to be made, but without knowing more…

Comment: @abarnert, thanks for the comments. By better, I primarily mean the efficiency of the code. Any improvement in that respect, besides the 'sorted collection' one you've already mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works.

Keeping a sorted collection in place of keeping list_b and sorting it on the fly will improve efficiency—but of course it may reduce efficiency elsewhere that matters more.

There's no other way to improve algorithmic complexity—dict lookups are constant-time, and iterating a list is as fast as iterating anything could possibly be.

You might be able to speed things up by a small constant factor by avoiding the need to hash each (a, b, c) tuple in various different ways, but I doubt that will make much difference.

You can speed things up by a few opcodes by various micro-optimizations related to variable scope and whether you yield values or return a generator, but it's hard to imagine that would ever matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should, assuming you want the ordering of `b` elements that the default `sorted()` imposes.